# how to prevent checkbox change event in vb.net desktop application

Tags: vb.net

I have a checkbox in my vb.net desktop application,on check change event iam performing some action.i want that on pageload check change event should not fire and it shows checkbox.checked on gui.

Answer (score 2):

Windows sometimes fires an event during form load, for whatever reason. It's really irritating, as you may have noticed. This is "by design" according to Microsoft.

You can initialize a variable (global or static), such as a boolean called "Loading" for example, to true. Then, in the form Shown event reset it to false. In the beginning of the event handler, check that variable and exit whenever Loading is true.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are creating the checkbox and after that you are setting it to checked.
You should create it already checked.

would be nice if you post the code how you create that checkbox and set it true.

Comment: My requirement is that if i save the checkbox in checked state.it should show the checked state when i retrieve the record but the change event should not get fired.thats why i can not use already checked option.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Click Event of `CheckBox` and 100% safe every time the checkBox is changing state